# intellij new maven project have an error

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I create a new maven web project in intellij.
I add tomcat server for it and in deployment section of server add my artifact.

My project name is `spline` and output directory in project structure-aritfact is:

```
C:\Users\abasaleh\Desktop\myChart\spline\out\artifacts\spline.
```

when I run it, I encounter with this alert:

```
C:\Users\abasaleh\Desktop\myChart\spline\out\artifacts\spline\spline.war not found for the web module.
```

and this server error:

```
[2014-02-24 01:58:34,679] Artifact spline: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
```

please help me. thankes.

my pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>spline</groupId>
<artifactId>spline</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


</project>
```

Comment: Can you show us the content of you pom.xml please?

Comment: I put pom.xml in question

Comment: I think by default, Maven will generate a Jar file. Can you try to add this line: <packaging>war</packaging>

Comment: I add it in pom.xml . but when do clean&packege the project, I encounter with this error:   **[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) on project spline: Error assembling WAR: webxml attribute is required (or pre-existing WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update mode) -> [Help 1]**

Comment: You need to have directory structure like <project_root>/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF with at least empty web.xml file in it, or specify webxml attribute in maven-war-plugin configuration and provide different web.xml location (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351948/webxml-attribute-is-required-error-in-maven)