# Project name declared in parent POM isn't expanded in a module filtered web.xml

Tags: maven

In my Maven multi-module project (you can have a look [here for other details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25674839/3127111)), I've enabled `web.xml` filtering for the webapp module, so that I can reference Maven properties in there.

I defined:

1. a property in the webapp module POM;
2. a property in the parent POM;
3. the Maven `<name />` element in the parent POM.

The properties in [1] and [2] are both expanded correctly in the packaged `web.xml` file, but the parent `<name />` tag is not — if I declare that element in the webapp-module it is correclty expanded.

Am I missing something? Is this the expected behaviour?

---

Here are the relevant parts of the various XML files involved.

### filtered (final) web.xml

```xml
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <display-name>shaker-multi-webapp webapp-value parent-value 1.0</display-name>
</web-app>
```

### web.xml

```xml
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <display-name>${project.name} ${webapp.prop} ${par.prop} 1.0</display-name>
</web-app>
```

### Webapp POM

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>sunshine.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>shaker-multi</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>shaker-multi-webapp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
```

### Parent POM

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>sunshine.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>shaker-multi</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>Shaker</name>

    <modules>
        <module>shaker-multi-core</module>
        <module>shaker-multi-runnable</module>
        <module>shaker-multi-webapp</module>
        <module>shaker-multi-webapp-muserver</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <par.prop>parent-value</par.prop>
    </properties>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the name declared in the parent POM, `${parent.name}` should be used instead of `${project.name}`, since project names aren't inherited (find more details in [Maven sources](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.3/maven-core/xref/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject.html#L466)).

Credits go to *rfscholte* from `#maven@irc.codehaus.org`.

Comment: Let's call it "A solution", not "The solution" ;) Most important is to know that the name is not inherited. I would probably choose for specifying the name in the pom of the webapp-module, since every project name should be unique (also nice to see in the console output).