# Maven with an explicit finalName won't work properly

Tags: java, maven, stack-overflow, maven-package

**1. Background**

My maven project has a lot of modules and submodules with `jars` and `wars` and everything works. I also can deploy it on server without any problem.

I decided to follow [this maven naming conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435460/maven-naming-conventions-for-hierarchical-multiple-module-projects/9461593#9461593), I am making some tests with `project.name` and `project.build.finalName` to have an appropriate name.

The pattern I defined to create `project.name` for the root artifact is `company-${project.artifactId}` and for the modules and sub-modules is `${project.parent.name}-${project.artifactId}`:

- company-any-artifact-any-module1
- company-any-artifact-any-module2-any-submodule1
- company-any-artifact-any-module2-any-submodule2

The pattern for `project.build.finalName` is `${project.name}-${project.version}`:

- company-any-artifact-any-module1-1.0.jar
- company-any-artifact-any-module2-any-submodule1-2.0.jar
- company-any-artifact-any-module2-any-submodule2-3.0.war

But instead of producing these files, maven gives me a `StackOverflowError`.

**2. The example to reproduce the error**

You can clone this example from github: https://github.com/pauloleitemoreira/company-any-artifact

In github, there is the [`master`](https://github.com/pauloleitemoreira/company-any-artifact/tree/master) branch, that will reproduce this error. And there is [`only-modules`](https://github.com/pauloleitemoreira/company-any-artifact/tree/only-modules) branch, that is a working example that uses `${project.parent.name}` to generate the jar `finalName` as I want.

Let's consider a maven project with one root pom artifact, one pom module and one submodule.

```
-any-artifact
     |
     |-any-module      
           |
           |-any-submodule
```

**2.1 any-artifact**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>any-artifact</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>company-${project.artifactId}</name>

    <modules>
        <module>any-module</module>
    </modules>

    <!-- if remove finalName, maven will not throw StackOverflow error -->
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.name}-${project.version}</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

**2.2 any-module**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>any-artifact</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.company</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.company.any-artifact</groupId>
    <artifactId>any-module</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>${project.parent.name}-${project.artifactId}</name>

    <modules>
        <module>any-submodule</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

**2.3 any-submodule**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>any-module</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.company.any-artifact</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.company.any-artifact.any-module</groupId>
    <artifactId>any-submodule</artifactId>

    <name>${project.parent.name}-${project.artifactId}</name>
</project>
```

**3. Problem**

When try to `mvn clean install`, maven gives me a `StackOverflowError`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.StringUtils.isEmpty(StringUtils.java:177)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.introspection.ReflectionValueExtractor.evaluate(ReflectionValueExtractor.java:194)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.introspection.ReflectionValueExtractor.evaluate(ReflectionValueExtractor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.java:266)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.java:143)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.java:143)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.java:429)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.java:143)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.java:143)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.java:429)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.java:143)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.java:143)
```

It is important to know that the error occurs only when we are working with submodules.  If we create a project with a root POM artifact and a jar module,  the error don't occur.

**4. The question**

Why this error occurs only when we are using submodules?

Any suggestion to solve my problem? Should I forget it and set `project.name` and `project.build.fileName` manually for each project, following the pattern I want?

**IMPORTANT UPDATED:**

Some answers just say to use **`&{parent.name}`**, but **it does not work**. Please, it is a question with a bounty, consider test your solution with `Maven version 3.3.9`, before answering this question.

*Maven version 3.3.9*

***Edit*** - Adding details to the question with the phase when the error occurs, things are working fine until the `prepare-package` phase, but the StackOverflow occurs at the `package` phase on maven lifecycle for the project.

Comment: where do you want .jar to be generated?

Comment: First if you try to generate war you have to change packaging to war instead furthermore remove the outputDirectory configuration cause it usually does not make sense.

Comment: @khmarbaise I updated the question to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: what do you expect to see in ${project.parent.name}?

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/a/26004524/2293534

Comment: `${parent.name}` doesn't work.

Comment: @SkyWalker it doen't work

Comment: What version of IntelliJ are you using?  It will be helpful in order to reproduce the issue and test a solution.

Comment: @M.Rizzo where do you get the info that he'd be using IntelliJ?

Comment: nice infinite loop :) don't you have some circular reference in placeholders  between parent and child module ?

Comment: @M.Rizzo I updated the question and reproduce this error just using prompt.

Comment: @eis I updated the question. Before, I was thinking it could be an IntelliJ error.  But now I get that I was wrong and we can reproduce the error just using `mvn clean install` in prompt.

Comment: @Gab It is weird, It seems like there is a circular reference in any place, I beleive it is not in my poms. Everything works fine when I use just a root artifact and a jar module. But the error occurs when I have an additional submodule.

Comment: @Paolo I can reproduce the problem with stackoverflowerror, but even with finalName commented out, I can't reproduce the situation where this would ever work. It won't give an error, but it won't work as a name either. As parent name is not inherited, I don't see how this could have ever worked.

Comment: @eis try to clean the project or check maven version. because I can make the project works when I comment our the `finalName`.

Comment: @Paulo I have cleaned, and I'm using the latest version. Maven doesn't support inheriting the parent name, at least not in the project layout you have on github.

Comment: [this](http://pastebin.com/raw/VMTRmdiJ) is what happens when removing finalName and then running, on Maven 3.3.9.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127227/discussion-between-paulo-and-eis).

Comment: Here are my 2 cents. There is no tag with <name> in the <parent> tag.Take a look at the maven project descriptor http://maven.apache.org/ref/3-LATEST/maven-model/maven.html. so ${project.parent.name} is not a valid expression at all. The right fix is to include the literal value in the name tag in each project pom. Also the name are not inheritable. So I think what you;re trying to do is not even supported either way officially..

Comment: Here is the exact same scenario that has been closed as not a problem if that helps.  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5784. Once you change the name to unique in each file everything should just checkout okay &  yes you can have the final build name the name you like provided you use valid expression.

Comment: Stack overflow error that you see is a common error that will happen when you use an invalid expression that starts with the correct identifier 'project' or 'pom' as the model builder is trying to evaluate expression recursively only to run out of stack size.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The strict answer to your question is that `${project.parent.name}` will **not** be resolved as part the model interpolation process. And in turn, you have a `StackOverflowError`, in a completely different place of the code, namely when... building the final JAR of your project.

#### Part 1: The Model built is wrong

Here's what happens. When you're launching a Maven command on a project, the first action it takes is creating the effective model of the project. This means reading your POM file, reasoning with activated profiles, applying inheritance, performing interpolation on properties... all of this to build the final Maven model for your project. This work is done by the [Maven Model Builder](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-model-builder) component.

The process of building the model is quite complicated, with a lot of steps divided in possibly 2 phases, but the part we're interested in here in the [model interpolation](http://maven.apache.org/components/ref/3.3.9/maven-model-builder/#Model_Interpolation) part. This is when Maven will replace in the model all tokens denoted by `${...}` with a calculated value. It happens after profiles are injected, and inheritance is performed. At that point in time, the Maven project, as represented by a `MavenProject` object, doesn't exist yet, only its `Model` is being built. And it is only after you have a full model that you can start constructing the Maven project from it.

As such, when interpolation is done, it only reasons in terms of the information present in the POM file, and the only valid values are the ones [mentioned in the model reference](http://maven.apache.org/components/ref/3.3.9/maven-model/maven.html). (This replacement is performed by the [`StringSearchModelInterpolator`](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/maven-3.3.9/maven-model-builder/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/model/interpolation/StringSearchModelInterpolator.java) class, if you want to look at the source code.) Quite notably, you will notice that the `<parent>` element in the model does **not** contain the name of the parent model. The class `Model` in Maven is actually generated with [Modello](https://codehaus-plexus.github.io/modello/) from a source `.mdo` file, and that source only defines [`groupId`, `artifactId`, `version` and `relativePath`](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/maven-3.3.9/maven-model/src/main/mdo/maven.mdo#L1993-L2079) (along with a custom `id`) for the `<parent>` element. This is also visible [in the documentation](http://maven.apache.org/components/ref/3.3.9/maven-model/maven.html#class_parent).

The consequence of all that, is that after model interpolation is performed, the token `${project.parent.name}` will not be replaced. And, further, the `MavenProject` constructed from it will have a name containing `${project.parent.name}` unreplaced. You can see this in the logs, in your sample project, we have

```
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] company-any-artifact
[INFO] ${project.parent.name}-any-module
[INFO] ${project.parent.name}-any-submodule
```

Meaning that Maven consider the actual name of the project `any-module` to be `${project.parent.name}-any-module`.

#### Part 2: The weirdness begins

We're now at a time when all of the projects in the reactor were correctly created and even compiled. Actually, everything should theoretically work just fine, but with only completely borked names for the projects themselves. But you have a strange case, where it fails at the creation of the JAR with the `maven-jar-plugin`. The build fails in your example with the following logs:

```
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ any-submodule ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] company-any-artifact ............................... SUCCESS [  0.171 s]
[INFO] ${project.parent.name}-any-module .................. SUCCESS [  0.002 s]
[INFO] ${project.parent.name}-any-submodule ............... FAILURE [  0.987 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

meaning that something went wrong well after the model was built. And the reason is that the plugin [injects the name of the project as a parameter](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/tags/maven-jar-plugin-2.4/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/jar/AbstractJarMojo.java?view=markup#l70):

> ```
> /**
>  * Name of the generated JAR.
>  *
>  * @parameter alias="jarName" expression="${jar.finalName}" default-value="${project.build.finalName}"
>  * @required
>  */
> private String finalName;
> ```

Notice `project.build.finalName` as the default value of the generated JAR name for the submodule. This injection, and the interpolation of the variables are done by another class called [`PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator`](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugin/PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.html).

So what happens in this:

- The JAR plugin on the `any-submodule` injects the final name of the project, named `${project.parent.name}-any-submodule`.
- Thanks for inheritance from the parent projects, and the declaration of `<finalName>` in your top-most POM project, it inherits `<finalName>${project.name}-${project.version}</finalName>`.
- Maven now tries to interpolate `${project.name}` for `any-submodule`.
- This resolves to `${project.parent.name}-any-submodule`, due to Part 1.
- Maven tries now to interpolate `${project.parent.name}` for `any-submodule`. This works correctly: the `MavenProject` is built and [`getParent()`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject.html#getParent()) will be called on the project instance, returning the concrete Maven parent project. As such, `${project.parent.name}` will try to resolve the name of `any-module`, which is actually `${project.parent.name}-any-module`.
- Maven now tries to interpolate `${project.parent.name}-any-module`, **but still on the `any-submodule` project instance**. For `PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator`, the root `"project"` on which to evaluate tokens hasn't changed.
- Maven now tries to interpolate `${project.parent.name}` on `any-submodule`, which, again, works correctly and returns `${project.parent.name}-any-module`.
- Maven now tries to interpolate `${project.parent.name}` on `any-submodule`... which works and returns `${project.parent.name}-any-module` so it tries to evaluate `${project.parent.name}`...

And you can see the endless recursion happening here, which results in the `StackOverflowError` you have. Is this a bug in `PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator`? This is unclear: it reasons on model values that were not correctly replaced in the first place. In theory, it could handle the special case of evaluating `${project.parent}` and create a new `PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator` working on this parent project, instead of always working on the current project. If you feel strongly about this, feel free to create [a JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG).

#### Part 3: Why it works without the sub module

With what has been said above, you could now deduce why it works in this case. Let's reason with what Maven needs to do to evaluate the final name, as has to be injected in the Maven Jar Plugin:

- The JAR plugin on the `any-module` injects the final name of the project, named `${project.parent.name}-any-module`.
- Thanks for inheritance from the parent project, and the declaration of `<finalName>` in your top-most POM project, it inherits `<finalName>${project.name}-${project.version}</finalName>`.
- Maven now tries to interpolate `${project.name}` for `any-module`.
- This resolves to `${project.parent.name}-any-module`, same as before.
- Maven tries now to interpolate `${project.parent.name}` for `any-module`. Just like before, this works correctly: the `MavenProject` is built and [`getParent()`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject.html#getParent()) will be called on the project instance, returning the concrete Maven parent project. As such, `${project.parent.name}` will try to resolve the name of `any-artifact`, which is actually `company-any-artifact`.
- Interpolation has succeeded and stops.

And you don't have any errors.

Comment: Very good explaination. I am, however somewhat split about the suggested Jira-Issue, since all properties are resolved that way, and a change like take might open doors to very 'creative' usages. Also, even if that were solved, the actual name of the module would still be the weird `${project.parent.name}-any-module` in the build logs. I think it would be better to consider this as special case earlier in the ModelBuilder (similar to how interpolation of `project.url` is handled, but only used if requested explicitly).

Comment: @blackbuild Yeah I'm not sure what would be the good way to solve this. The JIRA issue would be more to track this really. At the Model Builder level, it would be nice... I took a quick look at the code and it sounds like a non-trivial change though.

Comment: @blackbuild Also, I suppose the same could be done for other fields (what if the name depends on the parent description or inception year...?). Not sure this is really solvable at the model builder which is low level. I still find a bit weird that `PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator` fails like this, and it we want to fix that class, it doesn't look very complicated: just pass `project.getParent()` to the evaluation routine in case the expression starts with `project.parent`.

Comment: IMHO the ModelBuilder should be aware of this issue and in the current state at least throw an Exception instead of creating a 'weird' name. I would feel safe enough to disallow any parent access except the ones already in the model (artifactId, groupId, version, relativePath) and the addition of `name`, since this has usecases. Other parent references should IMHO not be allowed at all - ModelInterpolation does not resolve it either, so why should Plugin param evaluation work differently that the normal mechanism? This would only lead to more confusion.

Comment: @blackbuild Plugin param evaluation is already a bit different since accessing all of the parent params actually work (well, except the weird case here), when only a subset are supported in model interpolation. Even the name in the logs could possibly be improved by evaluating `project.getName()` like a plugin param (although that feels weird). But, yes, it starts to become not good practice, maybe access to parent parameters should be strictly restricted to specific ones, even in plugin params... I'll raise the issue on the Maven dev list and see others people thought.

Answer (score 4):

As I stated in my answer to [Difference between project.parent.name and parent.name ans use of finalName in pom.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40458000/difference-between-project-parent-name-and-parent-name-ans-use-of-finalname-in-p)

Let's first look at the basics:

as stated in [POM Reference](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#BaseBuild_Element):

> **finalName**: This is the name of the bundled project when it is finally built (sans the file extension, for example: my-project-1.0.jar). It defaults to ${artifactId}-${version}.
>
> **name**: Projects tend to have conversational names, beyond the artifactId.

So these two have different uses.

- `name` is purely informational and mainly used for generated documentation and in the build logs. It is not inherited nor used anywhere else. It is a human readable String and can thus contain any character, i.e. spaces or characters not allowed in filenames. So, this would be valid: `<name>My Turbo Project on Speed!</name>`. Which is clearly at least a questionable file name for an artifact.
- as stated above, `finalName` is the name of the generated artifact. It **is** inherited, so it should usually rely on properties. The only two really useful options are the default `${artifactId}-${version}` and the versionless `${artifactId}`. Everything else leads to confusion (such as a project named `foo` creating an artifact `bar.jar`). Actually, My turbo Project! would be valid, since this is a valid filename, but in reality, filenames like that tend to be rather unusable (try adressing a filename containing ! from a bash, for example)

---

So, as to why the Stackoverflow happens:

- `name` is not inherited
- `project.parent.name` also is not evaluated during interpolation, since the name is one of the few properties which are completey invisible to the children
- `parent.name` actually used to work in older Maven versions, but more due to a bug (also it is **deprecated** to access properties without the leading `project`).
- a missing property is not interpolated, i.e. stays in the model as is
- Therefore, in your effective pom for `any-submodule`, the value for `finalName` is (try it with `mvn help:effective-pom`) still: `${project.parent.name}-any-submodule`

So far so bad. Now comes the reason for the StackOverflow

Maven has an addtional feature called late interpolation that evaluates values in plugin parameters when they are actually used. This allows a pluing to use properties that are not part of the model, but are generated by plugins earlier in the lifecycle (this allows, for instance plugins to contribute a git revision to the final name).

So what happens is this:

**edit**: made the actual reason for the error clearer (see comments):

- The finalName for the jar plugin is evaluated:
  `@Parameter( defaultValue = "${project.build.finalName}", readonly = true )`
- The `PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator` kicks in and tries to evaluate the final name (`${project.parent.name}-any-submodule`, which contains a property expression ${project.parent.name}.
- The evaluator asks the model, which in turn returns the name of the parent project, which is: `${project.parent.name}-any-module`.
- So the evaluator tries to resolve this, which return `${project.parent.name}-any-module` (again), since a property is **always resolved against the current project**, the cycle begins again.
- A StackOverflowError is thrown.

---

## How to solve this

Sadly, you can't.

You need to explicitly specify `name` (as well as `artifactId`) for every project. There is no workaround.

Then, you **could** let `finalName` rely on it. I would however advise against it (see my answer to [Difference between project.parent.name and parent.name ans use of finalName in pom.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40458000/difference-between-project-parent-name-and-parent-name-ans-use-of-finalname-in-p))

The problem in changing the final name that way is that the name of the locally build artifact and the one in the repository would differ, so locally your artifact is named `any-artifact-any-module-any-submodule.jar`, but the artifact name in your repository would be still `any-submodule.jar`

## Suggestion

- If you really need to differentiate that fine, change the artifactId instead: `<artifactId>artifact-anymodule-anysubmodule</artifactId>`.
- Don't use dashes for the shortname to differentiate between levels of your structure.
- hint: the **path** of the module can be still `anymodule`, is does not need to be the actual artifactId of the module!
- While we are at it: use the `name` for what it was intended, to be human readable, so you might consider something more visually appealling (since this is the name that appears in the build log): `<name>Artifact :: AnyModule :: AnySubModule</name>`.
- It is actually very easy to simply create the name entries automatically using a very short groovy script.
- You could also write an enforce rule to enforce the naming of the artifactIds

Comment: Ah, we were writing at the same time. There's a bit more to the stackoverflow though: the core issue isn't the use of `project.parent`, this works fine, as demonstrated in the second project of the POM without submodules. The core issue is that there are 2 parents, and the current project instance on which the `PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator` works [didn't change](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40483587/1743880). The stackoverflow is because the parent name of `submodule`, is also its parent name. But since the current Maven project on which to evaluate expressions hasn't changed, it loops.

Comment: @Tunaki You are right, of course, this specific detail is not clear enough. Your answer is more detailed, anyway

Answer (score 2):

This is issue with attribute inheritance. 
Try to use `${parent.name}` instead of  `${project.parent.name}`. 
Look at: [Project name declared in parent POM isn't expanded in a module filtered web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003107/project-name-declared-in-parent-pom-isnt-expanded-in-a-module-filtered-web-xml).

---UPDATE---

Benjamin Bentmann (maven committier) said: "In general though, expressions of the form `${project.parent.*}` are a bad practice as they rely on a certain build state and do not generally work throughout the POM, giving rise to surprises".

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5126?jql=text%20~%20%22parent%20name%22

Maybe you should consider is using `${project.parent.*}` is a good way.

Comment: It doesn't work. My down voting is because it does not solve my problem. Actually, it worsens the problem. With your approach the final name changes from company-any-artifact-any-module-1.0.war to ${parent.name}-any-module-1.0.war.

Comment: Please, consider to test your solution with `Maven version 3.3.9` before answering.

Comment: I tried your example with `${project.parent.name}` but for me it works fine on mvn version 3.3.9. After invoked `mvn package` folder `company-any-artifact-any-module-1.0` was created under ` any-module/target/`

Comment: I don't know if this has impact but I tried with java version 1.8.0_102 and 1.7.0_79.

Comment: I updated the question. A `StackOverflowError` is thrown when we have a submodule.

Comment: Your solution (`parent.name` instead of `project.parent.name`) would use deprecated access, and does not work on newer versions, anyway. However, your update contains a very important hint.

Answer (score -1):

change pom.xml in  company-any-artifact to below and it will work .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>any-artifact</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>${project.groupId}</name>


    <modules>
        <module>any-module</module>
    </modules>

    <!-- if remove finalName, maven will not throw StackOverflow error -->
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.groupId}-${project.version}</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

change pom.xml in submodule to below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>any-artifact</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.company</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.company.any-artifact</groupId>
    <artifactId>any-module</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>  

  <!--   <name>${project.parent.name}-${project.artifactId}</name>  --> 

    <modules>
        <module>any-submodule</module>
    </modules>  
     <build>
        <finalName>${project.parent.name}-${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    </build> 
</project>
```

change submodule pom.xml to below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>any-module</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.company.any-artifact</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.company.any-artifact.any-module</groupId>
    <artifactId>any-submodule</artifactId>
        <!-- <name>${project.parent.name}-${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</name>    -->
    <build>
        <finalName>company-${project.parent.name}-${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

then the output was : **company-any-module-any-submodule-1.0-SNAPSHOT**

Comment: Can u check now its working ,seems having name and finalname both causing issue but by using above you get desired result,

Comment: It doesn't really work, a bit of chance. You have the correct output because the name of `any-module` default to its artifact id. So `${project.parent.name}` is the same as `${project.parent.artifactId}` and that works as explained [in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40483587/1743880). But the OP wants to generalize this by putting the final name in the top most POM, and this approach won't work there.

Comment: To see the issue, create another layer of POM parent project in the hierarchy, and it'll start failing...

Comment: then i think issue is with ${project.parent.name} which works in just the next sub-module but if you go one more level down it starts failing .

Answer (score -2):

Interesting! I started off cloning the repo and reproducing the error. I would appreciate any leads that can be taken from any of the steps mentioned below that helped me debug the problem -

1. [Maven Life Cycle Phases](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) 
   The phase where the issue occurred was the `package` phase of the lifecycle. Meaning `mvn package` reproduces the issue with your project.
2. Went through the stack trace lines in the error. Getting to know its the expression evaluation where it's failing -

   ```
   @Override
   public Object evaluate( String expr ) throws ExpressionEvaluationException {
       return evaluate( expr, null ); // Line 143
   }
   ```
3. It's also not the `finalName` attribute which was causing it. Since specifying the default value of the same 
   `<finalName>${artifactId}-${version}</finalName>`
   works fine with the same project configs.
4. Then tried changing the packaging of the `any-submodule` as

   ```
   <packaging>pom</packaging>
   ```

   and the error went away. Meaning while packaging as `jar` , `war` etc the expression evaluation is different and results in an overflow.
5. Modifying the `any-module` or the `any-submodule` `pom.xml` content I can say with some confidence that it's the `project.parent.name` that is causing a recursion in evaluating the expression and causing the stack overflow(How? - is something [I am still looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40458000/)..). Also, changing

   `<name>${project.parent.name}-${project.artifactId}</name>`

   to

   `<name>${parent.name}-${project.artifactId}</name>`

   works for me in the sense that I do not get an error but the jar generated is of type -

   `${parent.name}-any-module-any-submodule-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` and

   `${parent.name}-any-submodule-1.0-SNAPSHOT` respectively with the change.
6. Looking for the solution according to the requirement, I am seeking a tail to the recursion that you are using.

***Note*** - Still working on finding an appropriate solution to this problem.