# maven crashes during RPM creation

Tags: maven

I try to create an RPM using rpm-maven-plugin. Unfortunately, Maven reports

```
BUILD SUCCESS
```

but does not create the RPM. Instead, it crashes producing the following messages:

```
    constituent[0]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/lib/maven-model-builder-3.2.5.jar
    constituent[1]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/lib/maven-aether-provider-3.2.5.jar
    constituent[2]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/lib/maven-embedder-3.2.5.jar
    constituent[3]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/lib/aether-transport-wagon-1.0.0.v20140518.jar
    constituent[4]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/lib/maven-compat-3.2.5.jar
    constituent[5]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/lib/aether-api-1.0.0.v20140518.jar
    constituent[6]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar
    constituent[7]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/lib/jsoup-1.7.2.jar
    constituent[8]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/lib/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
    constituent[9]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/lib/aether-impl-1.0.0.v20140518.jar
    constituent[10]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/lib/maven-artifact-3.2.5.jar
    constituent[11]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/lib/plexus-interpolation-1.21.jar
    constituent[12]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/lib/sisu-guice-3.2.3-no_aop.jar
    constituent[13]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/lib/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.0.M1.jar
    constituent[14]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/lib/plexus-utils-3.0.20.jar
    constituent[15]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/lib/maven-settings-builder-3.2.5.jar
    constituent[16]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/lib/org.eclipse.sisu.plexus-0.3.0.M1.jar
    constituent[17]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/lib/maven-model-3.2.5.jar
    constituent[18]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/lib/aether-spi-1.0.0.v20140518.jar
    constituent[19]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar
    constituent[20]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/lib/wagon-http-2.8-shaded.jar
    constituent[21]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/lib/wagon-file-2.8.jar
    constituent[22]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/lib/maven-plugin-api-3.2.5.jar
    constituent[23]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/lib/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
    constituent[24]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar
    constituent[25]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/lib/cdi-api-1.0.jar
    constituent[26]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/lib/guava-18.0.jar
    constituent[27]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/lib/maven-settings-3.2.5.jar
    constituent[28]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/lib/wagon-http-shared-2.8.jar
    constituent[29]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/lib/wagon-provider-api-2.8.jar
    constituent[30]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/lib/commons-io-2.2.jar
    constituent[31]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/lib/plexus-cipher-1.7.jar
    constituent[32]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/lib/aether-connector-basic-1.0.0.v20140518.jar
    constituent[33]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/lib/jsr250-api-1.0.jar
    constituent[34]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
    constituent[35]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar
    constituent[36]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/lib/maven-repository-metadata-3.2.5.jar
    constituent[37]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/lib/javax.inject-1.jar
    constituent[38]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar
    constituent[39]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/lib/maven-core-3.2.5.jar
    constituent[40]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/lib/aether-util-1.0.0.v20140518.jar
    constituent[41]: file:/amdocs/external/maven-3.2.5/conf/logging/
    ---------------------------------------------------
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
            at org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.java:140)
            at org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.java:127)
            at org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.java:157)
            at org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.java:127)
            at org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.java:412)
            at org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.java:127)
            at org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.java:157)
            at org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.java:127)
            at org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.java:412)
            at org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.java:127)
            at org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.java:157)
```

The complete POM.xml is below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <parent>
        <groupId>parent.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>parenta.artifact</artifactId>
        <version>MAIN-SNAPSHOT</version>
      </parent>
      <groupId>parent.group</groupId>
      <artifactId>my-artifact</artifactId>
      <packaging>pom</packaging>
      <name>${project.parent.name}-${project.artifactId}</name>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>rpm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.rpm.plugin.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>generate-rpm</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>rpm</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
              <copyright>${copyright}</copyright>
              <group>${project.groupId}</group>
              <description>${project.artifactId}</description>
              <name>${rpm.product.name}-${project.name}-${rpm.product.layer}</name>
              <version>${project.version}</version>
              <requires></requires>
              <mappings>
                <mapping>
                  <directory>${rpm.base.dir}/config/directory>
                  <filemode>755</filemode>
                  <sources>
                    <source>
                      <location>${project.basedir}/Installation_CustomerRepresetativeDetails</location>
                    </source>
                    <source>
                      <location>${project.basedir}/scripts</location>
                    </source>
                    <source>
                      <location>${project.basedir}/properties</location>
                    </source>
                  </sources>
                </mapping>
              </mappings>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </project>
```

Comment: The issue is with `<name>${project.parent.name}`. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40336878/maven-with-an-explicit-finalname-wont-work-properly/40483587#40483587 It's very possibly the same issue.

Comment: Thanks. It is solved now.