# Maven build with JDK 6 fails due to UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: java, maven, version, maven-3, java-6

I'm trying to build with Maven 3.2.5 using the JDK 6 (in Eclipse Luna, Java EE Edition), and I keep getting the folowing error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/maven/cli/MavenCli : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:401)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:254)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.getMainClass(Launcher.java:144)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:266)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

After investigations, Maven downloads plexus-classworlds-2.5.2-sources.jar, which is compiled for the JDK 7, and that's the cause of the problem. Maven 3.2.5 is supposed to work with the JDK 6, so I don't understand what's happening.

Here the pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>fr.sacem.fwk</groupId>
        <artifactId>frmwk-parent</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.13</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>sacem-fwkweb</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Sacem Framework Web</name>
    <description>Socle technique de la Sacem</description>

    <dependencies>
           <!-- FwkCore -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>fr.sacem.fwk</groupId>
            <artifactId>sacem-fwkcore</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Wesso -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>fr.sacem.admap</groupId>
            <artifactId>wesso-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-jxpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-jxpath</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-resources</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-resources</artifactId>
            <version>X.Y.Z</version>
        </dependency>
         -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Gestion des Logs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- POI -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
          <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
          <artifactId>poi-contrib</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Struts -->
        <dependency>
              <!-- 
              <groupId>struts</groupId>
               -->
              <groupId>fr.sacem.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JUnit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>fr.sacem.fwk</groupId>
            <artifactId>fwkunit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

         <!-- API JavaEE
         <dependency>
             <groupId>javaee</groupId>
             <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
             <scope>provided</scope>
         </dependency>
          -->

         <!-- API Servlet -->
         <dependency>
             <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
             <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
             <scope>provided</scope>
         </dependency>

        <!-- API JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- API JTA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- YUI Compressor -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.yahoo.platform.yui</groupId>
            <artifactId>yuicompressor</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.7</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>ISO-8859-1</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <frmwk.project.build.sourceEncoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</frmwk.project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <frmwk.project.copyright>Copyright 2002-2015 SACEM.</frmwk.project.copyright>

        <frmwk.web.directory.build>${basedir}/build</frmwk.web.directory.build>

        <frmwk.web.directory.source.java>${basedir}/WEB-INF/sources/java/dev</frmwk.web.directory.source.java>
        <frmwk.web.directory.classes>${frmwk.web.directory.build}/classes</frmwk.web.directory.classes>

        <frmwk.web.directory.test.sources>${basedir}/WEB-INF/sources/java/tests</frmwk.web.directory.test.sources>
        <frmwk.web.directory.test.config>${basedir}/WEB-INF/config</frmwk.web.directory.test.config>
        <frmwk.web.directory.test.resources>${basedir}/WEB-INF/ressources</frmwk.web.directory.test.resources>
        <frmwk.web.directory.test.classes>${frmwk.web.directory.build}/test-classes</frmwk.web.directory.test.classes>

        <frmwk.web.directory.deploy>${basedir}/WEB-INF/deploiement</frmwk.web.directory.deploy>
        <frmwk.web.directory.templates>${frmwk.web.directory.deploy}/script/templates</frmwk.web.directory.templates>

        <frmwk.resources.jsp>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-jsp</frmwk.resources.jsp>
        <frmwk.resources.tools.yuicompressor>${maven.dependency.com.yahoo.platform.yui.yuicompressor.jar.path}</frmwk.resources.tools.yuicompressor>

    </properties>

    <build>
        <directory>${frmwk.web.directory.build}</directory>
        <sourceDirectory>${frmwk.web.directory.source.java}</sourceDirectory>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${frmwk.web.directory.source.java}</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <outputDirectory>${frmwk.web.directory.classes}</outputDirectory>

        <testSourceDirectory>${frmwk.web.directory.test.sources}</testSourceDirectory>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>${frmwk.web.directory.test.resources}</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*</include>
                </includes>
            </testResource>
            <testResource>
                <directory>${frmwk.web.directory.test.config}</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*</include>
                </includes>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <testOutputDirectory>${frmwk.web.directory.test.classes}</testOutputDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
                    JAVADOC
                 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                    <javadocExecutable>${frmwk.javadoc.executable}</javadocExecutable>
                    <docfilessubdirs>true</docfilessubdirs>

                    <locale>fr_FR</locale>

                    <version>true</version>
                    <author>true</author> 
                    <use>true</use> 
                    <private>false</private> 
                    <doctitle>${project.name} ${project.version}</doctitle> 
                    <windowtitle>${project.name} ${project.version}</windowtitle> 
                    <header>&lt;b&gt;${project.name} ${project.version}&lt;/b&gt;</header> 
                    <bottom>${frmwk.project.copyright}</bottom>

                    <stylesheetfile>${frmwk.web.directory.templates}/javadoc-stylesheet/stylesheet.css</stylesheetfile>
              </configuration>
              <executions>
                <execution>
                  <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>jar</goal>
                  </goals>
                </execution>
              </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
                    COMPILATION JAVA 1.6
                 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${frmwk.compile.source}</source>
                    <target>${frmwk.compile.target}</target>
                    <verbose>${frmwk.compile.verbose}</verbose>
                    <debug>${frmwk.compile.debug}</debug>
                    <encoding>${frmwk.project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    <showDeprecation>${frmwk.compile.deprecation}</showDeprecation>
                    <optimize>${frmwk.compile.optimize}</optimize>

                    <fork>${frmwk.compile.fork}</fork>

                    <executable>${frmwk.compile.executable}</executable>
                    <compilerVersion>${frmwk.compile.compilerVersion}</compilerVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
                    SOURCES JAVA
                 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- ================================= 
                    PREPARER LIVRAISON AMELY
                ================================= -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
                          target: copy-jars-to-delivery-dir                      
                         - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-jars-to-delivery-dir</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target name="Jar" description="Livrer la librairie">
                                <!-- S'assurer de l'existence du dossier de livraison -->
                                <mkdir dir="${frmwk.project.delivery.dir}" />

                                <!-- Copier les jar -->
                                <copy todir="${frmwk.project.delivery.dir}" overwrite="true" >
                                    <fileset dir="${frmwk.web.directory.build}">
                                        <filename name="*.jar"/>
                                    </fileset>
                                </copy>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
                          target: copy-javadoc-to-delivery-dir                      
                         - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-javadoc-to-delivery-dir</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target name="Javadoc" description="Livrer la documentation en ligne (api)">
                                <!-- S'assurer de l'existence du dossier dedestination -->
                                <mkdir dir="${frmwk.project.delivery.dir}/Javadoc/${project.artifactId}" />

                                <!-- Copier le dossier -->
                                <copy todir="${frmwk.project.delivery.dir}/Javadoc/${project.artifactId}" overwrite="true" >
                                    <fileset dir="${frmwk.web.directory.build}/apidocs">
                                        <filename name="**/*"/>
                                    </fileset>
                                </copy>

                                <!-- Copier le template de dossier Amely -->
                                <filter token="projectVersion" value="${project.version}"/>
                                <filter token="projectName"    value="${project.artifactId}"/>
                                <copy file="${frmwk.web.directory.templates}/amely/Javadoc/project.name/folder.amely"
                                      tofile="${frmwk.project.delivery.dir}/Javadoc/${project.artifactId}/folder.amely"
                                      filtering="true"/>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
                          target: zip-sources-non-public                     
                         - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>zip-sources-non-public</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target name="SourcesNonPublic" description="Livrer les sources (non public)">
                                <mkdir dir="${frmwk.project.delivery.dir}/SourcesNonPublic" />

                                <!-- Zipper l'intégralité du projet -->
                                <zip destfile="${frmwk.project.delivery.dir}/SourcesNonPublic/${project.artifactId}_${project.version}.srcnonpublic.zip">
                                    <fileset dir="${basedir}">
                                        <include name=".settings/**/*"/>
                                        <include name="commun/**/*"/>
                                        <include name="fwk/**/*"/>
                                        <include name="WEB-INF/**/*"/>
                                        <include name=".*"/>

                                        <exclude name="build/"/>
                                        <exclude name="*.log"/>
                                    </fileset>
                                </zip>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
                          target: fwkweb-jsp-zip                      
                         - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>fwkweb-jsp-zip</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target name="jsp-build-zip">
                                <delete dir="${frmwk.project.delivery.dir}/${frmwk.resources.jsp}.zip" failonerror="false" />

                                <zip zipfile="${frmwk.project.delivery.dir}/${frmwk.resources.jsp}.zip">
                                    <zipfileset dir="${basedir}" prefix="src/main/webapp">
                                        <include name="fwk/**/*"/>
                                    </zipfileset>
                                    <zipfileset dir="${basedir}/WEB-INF/ressources" prefix="src/main/resources">
                                        <include name="*.properties"/>
                                    </zipfileset>
                                </zip>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
            </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <!-- ================================= 
                          target: FRMWK-${project.version}.zip              
                         ================================= -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-artifacts</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifacts>
                                <artifact>
                                    <file>${frmwk.project.delivery.dir}/${frmwk.resources.jsp}.zip</file>
                                    <type>zip</type>
                                    <classifier>jsp</classifier>
                                </artifact>
                            </artifacts>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <profiles>
        <!--
        - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
            Profile: FRMWK
        - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
        -->
        <profile>
            <id>FRMWK</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <!-- Paramètre de build des modules FRMWK -->
                <frmwk.compile.executable>${JAVA_1_6_HOME}/bin/${JAVAC_EXE}</frmwk.compile.executable>
                <frmwk.javadoc.executable>${JAVA_1_6_HOME}/bin/${JAVADOC_EXE}</frmwk.javadoc.executable>

                <!-- Options de compilation -->
                <frmwk.compile.source>1.6</frmwk.compile.source>
                <frmwk.compile.target>${frmwk.compile.source}</frmwk.compile.target>
                <frmwk.compile.verbose>true</frmwk.compile.verbose>
                <frmwk.compile.debug>true</frmwk.compile.debug>
                <frmwk.compile.deprecation>true</frmwk.compile.deprecation>
                <frmwk.compile.optimize>true</frmwk.compile.optimize>
                <frmwk.compile.fork>true</frmwk.compile.fork>
                <frmwk.compile.compilerVersion>${frmwk.compile.source}</frmwk.compile.compilerVersion>

                <frmwk.project.delivery.dir>${FRMWK_DELIVRY_HOME}/V${project.version}</frmwk.project.delivery.dir>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

Comment: The problem is a bit tricky to explain. Don't hesitate to ask for precisions.

Comment: plexus-classworlds-2.5.2-sources.jar downgrade the jar version which is build in java 6

Comment: It would be useful to provide `pom.xml` configuration here.

Comment: Can't you use JDK7 and just decrease the compile version in the pom.xml file?

Comment: I added the pom.xml

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394456/java-6-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0

Comment: What does `mvn -v` command show you?

Comment: @JustinCooke I already did. I'm already using Maven 3.2.5, which *should* solve the problem...

Comment: @Tome I'm building in Eclipse. I forgot to mention it, sorry.

Comment: I guess you have checked that the 3.2.5 versions is the one Eclipse uses (see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531031/cannot-change-maven-version-in-eclipse-ide)

Comment: @Tome That was the cause of the problem. It still used the embedded Maven, which is the 3.3.3 version. Thank you! If you wirte that as an answer, I will be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An error message such as

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/maven/cli/MavenCli : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

will always indicate that a code compiled using JDK 7 is being executed by a non-compatible JRE version (most probably 6 or lower).

In your particular use-case (project *needs* JDK6), you have to ensure that the maximum Maven version used is 3.2.5 (the current latest official JDK6-compliant Maven version).

If your system hosts different versions of Maven, you will here have to force the version used.

And, depending on how Maven is launched, you can force that Maven version by:

- Command-line: set *M2_HOME* environment variable to point to that installation and be sure the executable is 3.2.5 (*PATH* environment variable)
- IDE: check that the IDE is configured to use the Maven version you need. See how to do that [here for IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-settings-page.html) and [there for Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531031/cannot-change-maven-version-in-eclipse-ide)