# Add Access-Control-Allow-Origin to Web Service

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, cors, spring-restcontroller

I have a webservice like:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ApplicationController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/Changes", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String inspect(ModelMap model) {
         model.addAttribute("msg", "example");

         return "index";
    }
}
```

in the link: `"localhost:8081/ChangesPDF/Changes?..."`

I'm trying to get the response of this webservice through Alfresco that is in the link: `"localhost:8080/share"`. I have different ports now (when I have same ports, this works good), so, with different ports I get the error in Alfresco:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at http://localhost:8081/ChangesPDF/Changes?... (Reason: Header CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

How can I add this header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a filter that sets the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to accepts domain "localhost:8081" (* for all).

Most probably you will find your answer here [cores-filter-not-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22846309/cors-filter-not-working-as-intended)

More explanation:

Create a filter class first

```
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;

        // can be moved to properties
        String[] allowDomain = {"localhost:8080","localhost:8081"};              


        String originHeader = request.getHeader("host");

        for(String domian : allowDomain){

            if(originHeader.endsWith(domian))

            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", originHeader);
            break;
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}
}
```

Add mapping to your web.xml class

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
    <filter-class>full name of your filter class here</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

you should correclty define the URL pattren in web.xml config according to your requirnment

Comment: But in my situation, how can I do this? I don't return a `HttpServletResponse response` so, if I make `response.setHeader` not makes effect.

Comment: Edited my answer to include how to setup filter

Comment: The url-pattern is which url?

Comment: try the new filter code, i have added both the domain in allowed list

Comment: I'm trying to modify web.xml but I got: `[INFO] WEB-INF/web.xml already added, skipping` in the maven. You know why?

Comment: Might be you are overriding your web.xml. There must only one and one web.xml that should existing. 
try posting you pom configuration too then i can help

Comment: Any idea? My pom.xml is in that link above.

Comment: Try generating web.xml like this ... Then edit it as required ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/26562633/3556394

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104746/discussion-between-python-and-prvs).

Comment: Alternative you can define the war plugin under build tag in pom file that takes web.xml file as an arguments <plugin>            
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <webXml>src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>        
  </configuration>
</plugin>

Comment: It works but with @CrossOrigin too. Both solutions merged.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring 4.2+, you can use the [@CrossOrigin](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework) annotation :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ApplicationController {

    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(value="/Changes", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String inspect(ModelMap model) {
         model.addAttribute("msg", "example");

         return "index";
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you'll need to register a CORS filter in your Spring application. Something like [this](https://gist.github.com/zeroows/80bbe076d15cb8a4f0ad).

Answer (score 0):

I think your code may need to use Spring's `@CrossOrigin` annotation, *e.g.*:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;

....

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ApplicationController {

    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(value="/Changes", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String inspect(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("msg", "example");

        return "index";
    }
}
```

This will allow **all** origins, which may or may not be enough for your needs.

For reference, I found the above described in [this article](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/), and mentioned in the [Spring blog here](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework).

Hope this helps!

Comment: What happens if you use the `@CrossOrigin` annotation on the entire controller class, rather than on individual methods?