# After converting a Dynamic web project which was working in Eclipse to Maven Project Build is not completed

Tags: spring, maven

I was trying to replicate the spring program as per the [link](https://www.java4s.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-spring-mvc-3-2-hello-world-example-in-eclipse/) , the dynamic web project worked fine ,but I wanted to convert it to maven structure and run the same . 
Tried to right click on the project 
I have tried to do update project and then tried to do maven build getting the below error in console

```
INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ SpringMvcHelloWorldProgram ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\ragupat\eclipse-workspace\SpringMvcHelloWorldProgram\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ SpringMvcHelloWorldProgram ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ SpringMvcHelloWorldProgram ---
[INFO] Not copying test resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ SpringMvcHelloWorldProgram ---
[INFO] Not compiling test sources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ SpringMvcHelloWorldProgram ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) @ SpringMvcHelloWorldProgram ---
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields (file:/C:/Users/ragupat/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.3.1/xstream-1.3.1.jar) to field java.util.Properties.defaults
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [SpringMvcHelloWorldProgram] in [C:\Users\ragupat\eclipse-workspace\SpringMvcHelloWorldProgram\target\SpringMvcHelloWorldProgram-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\Users\ragupat\eclipse-workspace\SpringMvcHelloWorldProgram\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [149 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: C:\Users\ragupat\eclipse-workspace\SpringMvcHelloWorldProgram\target\SpringMvcHelloWorldProgram-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.390 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-07-01T13:18:14+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) on project SpringMvcHelloWorldProgram: Error assembling WAR: webxml attribute is required (or pre-existing WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update mode) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

Comment: You have `web.xml`?

Comment: yes i am using the same code as provided in the link

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351948/webxml-attribute-is-required-error-in-maven/13130839

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["webxml attribute is required" error in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351948/webxml-attribute-is-required-error-in-maven)